# Apply a filter to a child that is within its parents loop

Tags: python, django

This is driving me mad (I really have looked everywhere - but I know it must be easy and I'm just being a tad think)

How do I add a filter to a child of a parent (one to many)?  The code below provides a list of companies in a table, then on the same page/ table, each company has a list of "charges" which is attributed to that company; thanks to the ForeignKey and using "charge_set" it works great.  However, I would like to add a filter to the "charges" for status (so exclude "outstanding" status)

In ROR I would have simply placed the following

```
<% company.charges.where(status: "Outstanding").each do |charge| %>
```

AIUI, I can't do this with Python/ Django in the view; so how would I go about adding a simple filter to the child of the parent within this loop?

---

```
from django.db import models

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Charge(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    charge_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

---

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from companies.models import Company, Charge, Filing
from django.http import HttpResponse

def watch_list(request):
    companies = Company.objects.order_by('-data_date')

    return render(request,'company_watch/watch_list.html',{'companies':companies})
```

---

```
{% for company in companies %}
<tr>
   <td>{{company.name}}</td>
   <td>
      <ul>
         {% for charge in company.charge_set.all %}
         <li>{{charge.charge_id}}</li>
         {% endfor %}
      </ul>
   </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just grab the `company` and filter the children. If you want to the children on the backend:

```py
company = Company.objects.get('...')
outstanding_children = Charge.objects.filter(company = company, status = "Outstanding")
```

If you want to display the children on the frontend:

```
{% for company in companies %}
<tr>
   <td>{{company.name}}</td>
   <td>
      <ul>
         {% for charge in company.charge_set.all %}
             {% if charge.status == "Outstanding" %} 
                 <li>{{charge.charge_id}}</li>
             {% endif %}
         {% endfor %}
      </ul>
   </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: A quick one - I am applying the second suggestion, but now finding limited.  I would prefer the first method, but unsure how to associate "company"  from the associated recorded on the view?

Comment: You could create a `dict` mapping of the companies and a list of its chargers, and then pass it to the context. Using `{% for key, value in dictionary.items %}` will allow you to access the company and then the list of charges within your template.

Comment: Sorry; I feel like I'm missing something - I have my "companies" in view.py which in my Html I have a loop to produce a list of companies in a table (see my question); how do I change that to `company = Company.objects.get('...')` to then use the data from `each company` to both produce a list of companies and then enable a filter on the Charges?  Hope that makes sense - if not I will start a new question

Comment: I am afraid I am confused on what exactly you are asking. Making a new question and clarifying it with some code examples of what you expect to happen might make it more clear -- feel free to post the question here afterwards, and I'll try to help out.